# Cannot connect to Dell Powervault MD3220i

Tags: dell, network-attached-storage

We have bought a brand new PowerVault MD3220i but while configurating the system somehow it disconnected and stop giving response. I can still ping the machine, which means network interface still ON but whenever I try to login Storage Management Console says that it is "unidentified device".

MD3220i does not have any additional interface on it, that lets us to reconfigure or reset the configuration so how can we overcome this problem ?

Thanks
Baris

Comment: If you bought it brand new, my guess would be that it's under a current support contract from Dell. If that's the case then my suggestion would be to call their technical support number.